# TSQL RETURN statement does not stop a batch from executing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, return

From Books Online, the `RETURN` statement was defined as:

> Exits unconditionally from a query or procedure. RETURN is immediate and complete and can be used at any point to exit from a procedure, **batch**, or statement block. Statements that follow RETURN are not executed.

Note that it can stop a `batch`. However, my testing does not comply with this. Below is my testing code.

```
IF DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'data', N'Version') IS NULL
    RETURN;

USE data;
```

I select this code and run it in SQL Server Management Studio. The result is:

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
> Database 'data' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

As I understand, since my code does not contain `GO`, so it should all in a single batch. Because the database *data* does not exist, the `RETURN` statement should stop execution and the `USE` statement will not get a chance to run. But the result is simply not what I think. Anyone can help?

## Update

I can confirm my testing code is in a single batch. I use SQL profiler captured `SQL:BatchStarting` and `SQL:BatchCompleted` events and below is the result.

[image]

The `SQL:BatchStarting` and `SQL:BatchCompleted` events have the same SQL text.

Comment: a batch is the entire script (until the GO batch terminator in SSMS) so the SQL:BatchStarting and SQL:BatchCompleted events show the same text.  You need to trace the SQL:StmtStarting and SQL:StmtCompleted for more granularity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx

> USE is executed at both compile and execution time and takes effect
>   immediately.

It is executed at compile time. This is the reason.

Comment: Hmm, it seems the *USE* statement will always been executed. There is no way to skip it. Thanks.

Comment: The use statement is checked at compile time which means that the database has to be available when it is compiled even before execution.